# Query/Search 3 JSON files connecting the items like an SQL Database join would

Tags: javascript, php, json, search

### Question

Assuming I have 3 JSON files,

Is there a way to get data from 3 JSON files where the first 2 JSON datasets contain array of `List` objects and array of `Tag` objects and the 3rd JSON databaset contains an array of objects that have a `List.id` and a `Tag.id` to connect a tag to a list just like you would do with 3 relational database tables in SQL

**Example search**
So for example if I need to get all `Tags` that belong to `List.id` 1 I would look in JSON file/dataset `List_Tags.json` and look for record that have properties `list_id == 1` and all matching objects would return the `tag_id` and use it to look in `Tags.json` file/dataset to search for all tags with `tag.id` property matching the IDs from the `List_Tags.json` result

I can use JavaScript or PHP

#### How I think it might could work:

- search `List_Tags.json` data for all records with `list_id` == 1`
- save those records if any to an array variable
- now search `Tags.json` file/dataset by iterating over each array object searching for items with `tag.id == ID_FROM_CURRENT_ARRAY_ITERATION_LOOP`
- each tag item that matches previous step, add to a new array
- when done, return the new array which contains all the Tags that belong to List with List ID == 1

Below is the JSON file data and example data

---

### JSON Files Object Properties

- **File 1** = `Lists.json` has array of objects with

  - id
  - name
  - description
- **File 2** = `Tags.json` has array of objects with:

  - id
  - name
  - description
- **File 3** = `List_Tags.json` has array of objects that connect tags to a list with:

  - list_id
  - tag_id

---

### Example JSON file data:

```
// Lists.json File
ListsJsonData =[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "List 1 Name",
    "description": "List 1 Description"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "List 2 Name",
    "description": "List 2 Description"
  }
];

// Tags.json File
TagsJsonData =[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Tag 1 Name",
    "description": "Tag 1 Description"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Tag 2 Name",
    "description": "Tag 2 Description"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tag 3 Name",
    "description": "Tag 3 Description"
  }
];

// Lists_Tags.json File
ListsJsonData =[
  {
    "list_id": 1,
    "tag_id": 1
  },
  {
    "list_id": 1,
    "tag_id": 2
  },
  {
    "list_id": 2,
    "tag_id": 2
  }
];
```

---

Comment: What a problem  are you waiting?

Comment: @splash58 The question/problem is at the botton of my post...Asking if there is a way to get data from 3 JSON datasets in the way that you would get data from 3 Relational databases where the 3rd table is a connector/join table to connect dataset 1 and 2

Comment: I understood. Let's wait guru :)

Comment: @splash58 I updated my question to make it more clear hopefuilly

Comment: @splash58 I see you are really good with PHP arrays.  If all my JSON data was converted into Multi-dimensional arrays, do you think my theory in the updated questions of how to search each array would work in PHP.  Thanks for any help

Comment: I think, you are right. Just two array_filter will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using PHP I want to solve it with JavaScript as well now.

```
<?php

$list_json = '[{"id":1,"name":"List 1 Name","description":"List 1 Description"},{"id":2,"name":"List 2 Name","description":"List 2 Description"}]';

$list_array = json_decode($list_json);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($list_array);
echo '<hr>';

/////////////////////
///

// search tags_array for id == $id.  Array can be multi-dimensional array or array of objects
function searchForTagId($id, $tags_array) {
    foreach ($tags_array as $tag) {
        if ($tag->id == $id) {
            return $tag;
        }
    }
    return null;
}



$tags_json = '[{"id":1,"name":"Tag 1 Name","description":"Tag 1 Description"},{"id":2,"name":"Tag 2 Name","description":"Tag 2 Description"},{"id":3,"name":"Tag 3 Name","description":"Tag 3 Description"}]';

$tags_array = json_decode($tags_json);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($tags_array);
echo '<hr>';

/////////////////////


$list_tags_json = '[{"list_id":1,"tag_id":1},{"list_id":1,"tag_id":2},{"list_id":2,"tag_id":2}]';

$list_tags_array = json_decode($list_tags_json);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($list_tags_array);
echo '<hr>';

//////////////////////


$list_1_tags = array();
foreach ($list_tags_array as $list_tag) {
    if ($list_tag->list_id == 2) {
        $list_1_tags[] = searchForTagId($list_tag->tag_id, $tags_array);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($list_1_tags);
```